# Eclipse Android cant find resource

Tags: android, eclipse

I use eclipse with android. Android 2.2 (API 8) and all extras have been installed via the sdk manager.

When I click on New->Android Application Project and do the follwing:
->

Application Name: App
Project Name: App
Package Name: com.example.app

Minimum Required SDK: API 8
Target SDK: API 21
Compile With: API 8
Theme: none (I can only choose none)

--next--

create custom launcher icon
create activity
create project in workspace

--next--

--next--

create activity
Master/Detail Flow (I can only choose this one, otherwise it wont work)

--next--
Object Kind: Item
Object Kind Plural: Items

--finish--

Now the Console Output looks like this:
->

```
[2015-05-15 11:59:29 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\App\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:29 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:195: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:199: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:114: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:116: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:118: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:111: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:124: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:141: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:135: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:149: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:153: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:157: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:167: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:171: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:175: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:94: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:102: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:189: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:191: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:177: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:179: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:181: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:183: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:185: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:203: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:187: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:60: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:64: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:buttonBarButtonStyle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:30: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:buttonBarStyle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:39: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:buttonBarButtonStyle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:buttonBarStyle'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:162: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:160: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:161: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:159: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] 
[2015-05-15 11:59:30 - App] C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.


Problems output looks like:
->
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\User\workspace1\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

How can I fix my problem now?
Why can I choose none only as theme?
Why can I choose Master/Detail Flow as activity only?

Comment: chek with laltoo's ans nd also import library from appcomact v7 ...nd make referance of that libary in you project

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile an app with API level 21 features with API level 8 build environment.

Set the "compile with" to API level 21.

Comment: Because you need to set your compile SDK to 21 to use the v21 resources.

Comment: i understand, but i set everything to 8. i can try installing api 21, but i wanted to use api 8, cause this way i can reach more android versions

Comment: You can run apps compiled on SDK 21 on lower runtime versions.

Comment: i've read that api 21 contains things that api 8 doesnt, so this could lead to running errors, because older versions couldnt work with an app compiled with api 21.
i just downloaded api 21 and it "works" but the console automatically print false several times, when i press run